# Dropping rows of dataframe in a for-loop in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have multiple dataframes with multiple columns as this:

```
DF = 
    A    B    C   metadata_Colunm
r1  6    3    9   r1 
r2  2    1    1   r2
r3  5    7    2   r3
```

How can I use a for-loop to iterate over each column to make a new dataframe and then remove rows where values are below 5 for each new dataframe?
The result should look like this:

```
DF_A=
      A   metadata_Colunm
      6   r1
      5   r1

DF_B=
      B   metadata_Colunm
      7   r3

DF_C=
      C   metadata_Colunm
      9   r1
```

What I have done so far is to make a list over the columns I will use (all excluding metadata) and then go trough the columns as new dataframes. Since I also need to preserve the metadata I add the metadata-column as part of the new dataframe:

```
DF = DF.drop("metadata_Colunm")
ColList = list(DF)
for item in ColList:
    locals()[f"DF_{str(item)}"] = DF[[item, "metadata_Colunm"]]
    locals()[f"DF_{str(item)}"] = locals()[f"DF_{str(item)}"].drop(locals()[f"DF_{str(item)}"][locals()[f"DF_{str(item)}"].item > 0.5].index, inplace=True)
```

But using this I get  "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'item'.

Any suggestions for making this work, or any other solutions, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfs = {}
for col in df.columns[:-1]:
    df_new = df[[col, 'metadata_Colunm']]
    dfs[col] = df_new[df_new[col] >= 5]
```

Comment: [Should df_new be defined like that?](https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/indexing/indexing21.html).

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the definition of df_new, your link is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply a filter to the dataframe(s) instead of using a loop

```
def filter(df, threshold=5):
    for column in df.columns:
        df = df[df[column]>=threshold]
```

Then apply the filer to all your dataframes:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3...]
for df in dfs:
    filter(df)
```

Comment: This works, but only once you've already sliced ```df``` into the three separate dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a dictionary to add your new dataframes to, like this:

```py
dictionary = {}
for col in df.columns[:-1]: # all columns but last
    new_df = df.loc[:, (col, 'metadata_column')] # make slices
    for index, row in new_df.iterrows():
        if new_df.loc[index, col] < 5: # remove < 5
            new_df.drop(index=index, inplace=True)
    dictionary[col] = new_df # add to dictionary so you can refer to later
```

You can then call each dataframe via e.g. `dictionary['A']`.

According to [this](https://tedboy.github.io/pandas/indexing/indexing21.html) its best practice to slice the dataframe using `df.loc()` as opposed to `df[]`.